# nltk custom grammar for chunking dates using RegexpParser

Tags: python, regex, date, parsing, nltk

Using the information extraction from this blog [post](https://gist.github.com/alexbowe/879414), I'm trying to define a grammar that includes the addition of dates as a new chunk with the following grammar;

```
grammar = r"""
    NBAR:
        {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns

    NP:
        {<NBAR>}
        {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
    DATE -> MONTH SEP DAY SEP YEAR
    SEP -> "/"
    MONTH -> DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT
    DAY -> DIGIT | DIGIT DIGIT
    YEAR -> DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT
    DIGIT -> '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | '0'
```

But this throws an illegal chunk pattern when I call `chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)`, Any ideas of how I can include the dates which are always represented as 8 digits `DD/MM/YYYY` or in the long form where the month is spelled out and the date is followed by the ordinal indicator `st,nd,  or th` so that the result would be `DDthMONTHYYYY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing apples and oranges. Only your first two expansions are valid nltk `RegexpParser` rules, so you get an error on the third. Convert the rest to the same format: Change the separator from `->` to `:`, then write the expansions as [`RegexpParser`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser) expressions. Note that you are working with a chunker, not a hierarchical parser. (See the above documentation, and also all of [Chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) of the NLTK book.)

Comment: PS. Note that the chunk parser matches against POS tags on tokens, not single characters. You might want to take a step back and reconsider the tools you're using for this task...